# Invoke Javascript function from Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to configure push notifications for my Angular project. I tried with the `AngularFire` module, but I am facing issues - https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/2299. So I thought of using vanilla Javascript code. So I created Javascript function which will display the Notification permission request dialog and write the token to the console. And I am able to call the function from Angular. But instead of writing the token to the console, I need to save the token in my database, so that I can associate the token to users of my application and send the notification to specific users. I couldn't find any ways to do this. Here is my Javascript function which shows the browser notification prompt and writes the token to the console.

```
var requestForPermission = function () {
  messaging.requestPermission().then(m => {
    messaging.getToken().then(t => {
      console.log(t);
    });
  });
}
```

And in typescript I created a function like this.

```
declare function requestForPermission(): any;
```

And finally calling this function from a typescript function.

```
toggleBrowserNotification() {
  requestForPermission();
}
```

I tried to return the token, messaging object etc, but I don't know how to consume these object in Typescript.

Comment: What do you mean with your database? where do you need The token? It Is not clear.

Comment: Yes, I need to store the notification token (registration id) to my application database so that I can associate it to users and send a notification to specific users.

Comment: do you have already the code in the front to save that token? Is that code in the same class that "toggleBrowserNotification"?

Comment: Problem is my code to save the token to the database is in Angular typescript. And I need to get the token from Javascript to Typescript / Angular so that I can save the token to database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood fine your problem, you can try this.

**JS**

```
var requestForPermission = async function () {
    let m = await messaging.requestPermission();
    return await messaging.getToken();
}
```

**TS**

```
toggleBrowserNotification() {
   requestForPermission()
       .then(t => this.myTokenSaverService.savetoken(t)) //All succesful
       .catch(e=> console.log(e)); //Error getting permission or token
}
```

Regards,